# Inserting dropdown value to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to insert dropdown values into my database but it won't insert. I'm not getting any errors either so I'm kinda confused, still new and trying to learn PHP :)

So here's a sample of the dropdown:

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
                <span class="label-input100" style="font-size: 17px; color: black;">I lock my computer screen when I walk away from it (Windows + L)</span>
                <select class="selection-2" name="q1">
                    <option selected disabled hidden></option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

and here's my PHP code (LMK if you need the whole PHP code, only posted these as I thought this is where the errors come from):

```
if(empty($emailaddress_err) && empty($q1_err) && empty($q2_err) && empty($q3_err) && empty($q4_err) && empty($q5_err) && empty($q6_err) && empty($q7_err) && empty($q8_err) && empty($q9_err) && empty($q10_err)){
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO employees (emailaddress, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
     
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssss", $emailaddress, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8, $q9, $q10);
        
        // Set parameters
        $emailaddress = $emailaddress;
        $q1 = $_POST['q1'];
        $q2 = $_POST['q2'];
        $q3 = $_POST['q3'];
        $q4 = $_POST['q4'];
        $q5 = $_POST['q5'];
        $q6 = $_POST['q6'];
        $q7 = $_POST['q7'];
        $q8 = $_POST['q8'];
        $q9 = $_POST['q9'];
        $q10 = $_POST['q10'];
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

}

PHP code is on top of the index HTML so here's my form action:

```
<form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="alert('Success!');">
```

and the submit button:

```
<button class="myButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Have you got error reporting switched on? [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman I don't think I have, actually. Let me try this one.

Comment: Are you sure that the code is actually entering the IF block? You might need to so some echo/log lines to track where the code is going.

Comment: Are you sure the IF statement is correct? It looks like you're saying IF q1 (plus all the other values) ARE EMPTY insert them. But then is there a null condition on the columns in the DB? If there's a "cannot be null" then it won't insert.

Comment: @user1020496 The variables in the `if` statement are for any errors that are set. He's saying if all those errors are empty, continue.